# VSCode can't find 'process' with two tsconfig.jsons

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an angular 6 project, to which I want to add a couple of command line utilities, also written in Typescript. Since the project was created with `ng`, all the sources are in the `/src` directory.

I've created a `/tools` directory (a sibling of src) with its own `tsconfig.json`, to which I've added `"types": ["node"]`. I have also installed the @types/node package.

I have a simple source:

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

The file compiles and runs properly. However, VSCode complains that `process` is undefined. Process is obviously defined, as the code compiles properly.

Only VSCode isn't aware of that. It's as if VSCode doesn't consult tsconfig.json and doesn't know it should use the Node types.

How can I tell VSCode that it should use the Node types?

Comment: Can you provide some more details of the file layout (or just publish your repository) so I can reproduce the problem?  In what directory is @types/node installed?  In what directory is the other tsconfig.json file and what does it contain?

Comment: I can't release my repository, it contains some data files that belong to a client who does not want to expose them. I tried to reproduce the problem with a new Angular application, with the same folder structure and all - and there it works! I'll try to figure out how to reproduce it and publish a repository.